# The repository does not have a Release file

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Installing Humble Hawksbill on Ubuntu Jammy 22.04 in virtualbox.
Following instructions from http://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html

```
    lennart@ml-dev:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y \
  build-essential \
  cmake \
  git \
  python3-colcon-common-extensions \
  python3-flake8 \
  python3-flake8-blind-except \
  python3-flake8-builtins \
  python3-flake8-class-newline \
  python3-flake8-comprehensions \
  python3-flake8-deprecated \
  python3-flake8-docstrings \
  python3-flake8-import-order \
  python3-flake8-quotes \
  python3-pip \
  python3-pytest \
  python3-pytest-cov \
  python3-pytest-repeat \
  python3-pytest-rerunfailures \
  python3-rosdep \
  python3-setuptools \
  python3-vcstool \
  wget


   Hit:1 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
    Get:2 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [109 kB]
    Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]     
    Get:4 http://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99,8 kB] 
    Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [11,4 kB]
    Ign:6 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
    Hit:7 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu jammy InRelease
    Err:8 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release
      404  Not Found [IP: 64.50.236.52 80]
    Reading package lists... Done
    E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
    N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
    N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402151/the-repository-does-not-have-a-release-file./) by [lennarn](https://answers.ros.org/users/107937/lennarn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
>    Err:8 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release
> ```

you appear to have the ROS 1 package repository configured on your Ubuntu Jammy system.

ROS 1 does not support Ubuntu Jammy, hence there is no "release file" there for `apt` to download.

You'll have to either:

1. remove the line which says something like `deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy main` from `/etc/apt/sources.list`, or
2. remove the `.list` file from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` (note the `.d` there) which contains that line

then try again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [wenchao](https://answers.ros.org/users/137395/wenchao/) on 2023-04-15**:
Such line, as mentioned in 1, doesn't exist there, but 2 worked for me. The file name was ros-latest.list.

**Comment by [bak](https://answers.ros.org/users/148064/bak/) on 2023-05-08**:
how you solve this ? i can't delete the .list !!!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-05-08**:
You'll probably have to remove it using `sudo rm`, as `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` is only writable by `root` (or users with `root`-level access).